# GoogleMaps and GoogleAds in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

I have project that uses GoogleMaps.
Project works fine.

but I have moved project from vm mac to other computer mac os.
after that, project raised error like below.

```
No such module 'GoogleMaps'
```

why is this error raised after move project?
thank you.

(and in other project that I moved, I have met like this error

```
  Umbrella header 'GoogleMobileAds.h' not found
  Could not build Objective-C module 'GoogleMobileAds'
```

this project has bridge file but that's for other library
)
any idea for this problem?

Comment: Did you tried Cleaning your project and building it again secondly you are using bridging header and you switched project from vm to Mac so you must assign the new path of bridging header in build setting (Project setting ). after doing these two steps build again hope it helps. As according to me such error exist as path is changed and if you using pods install them again

Comment: first project haven't bridging file. and I tried clean and rebuild.
but that's not working.
second project has bridging file, but that's for other libraries.
that libraries didn't raise any error.

Comment: " I have moved project"... how did you move, throught git or just pasted there?

Comment: are you using pod?

Comment: yes. I'm using pod.
and I have moved project by copy/paste.

Comment: I have solved this problem by uninstall pod and install again.
I have met new error
    " Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self question self answer

I solved this problem.

- First I removed all the libraries in Podfile.
  and then I ran "pod install" to remove all the libraries from project.
- I attached again libraries to Podfile.
  and executed again "pod install" to reinstall all the libraries.
  then errors are disappeared.
- I have met new error "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1".  To fix this goto project root folder in terminal and exeucted follow command

  xattr -rc .

after that everything is ok. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

First, always try cleaning the project as suggested. If that didn't work,  try manually installing the framework. [Here's Google's page on how to.](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start#manually_using_the_sdk_download)